# How to avoid labels of inputs

Tags: cakephp

I have this code in cake php but it generates a bunch of labels along with the input that I do not like. How can I get rid of them? I just want the input.

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('user_role', array('value'=> '2'));
echo $this->Form->input('user_username');
echo $this->Form->input('user_password', array('type' => 'password'));
echo $this->Form->input('user_fname');
echo $this->Form->input('user_lname');
echo $this->Form->input('user_email');
echo $this->Form->input('user_phone');
echo $this->Form->input('user_cellphone');
echo $this->Form->input('user_address1');
echo $this->Form->input('user_address2');
echo $this->Form->input('user_city');
echo $this->Form->input('user_zip');
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried consulting [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Labels are good for usability. But you can remove them in each form field adding the following:

```
$this->Form->input('user_username', array( 'label' => false ));
```

You can also disable labels by default when creating the form:

```
$this->Form->create('User', array('inputDefaults' => array('label' => false)));
```

Futher information available at their site:

- http://book.cakephp.org/view/1398/options-label
- http://book.cakephp.org/view/1616/x1-3-improvements

Comment: One small question... the reason why i am not using that label.. is because it does not allow me to position it.. right now the label and the inputs look weird, unorganized if one label is longer than the others

Comment: @user Sounds more like a CSS layout problem than a problem with labels as such.

Comment: You must use css to make your form "well positioned". Take a look at this post: http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/layout_form_without_tables_with_css_trick.aspx

Comment: you can use $this->Form->control('user_username'); which will show only input field, no label.